# While writing Css property of the text not getting expected output

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want my text display property contains Open Sans,Regular,Crisp.
Class which I prepared is below.

```
.sms {
    font:"Open Sans" "Regular";
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16pt;
    color:#04323b;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-smooth: Crisp;

}
```

but not getting exact.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that the shorthand font property should consist of multiple values:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Shorthand_properties#Font_Properties

Here's a correct CSS declaration:

```
font: bold 16pt 'Open Sans';
```

Also, a `font-smooth` property exists in the [W3C drafts](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-font/#font-smooth), but there is no browser support at this time.

Comment: Not completely correct about font-smooth. It appears to be a new property from css3: http://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/font-smooth.htm But it looks like it has almost no support in browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Use this, rest all are correct

```
font-family: "Open Sans";
font-weight: normal;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
font-family:"Open Sans";
font-weight:normal;
font-size:16pt;
color:#04323b;
letter-spacing:1px;
font-smooth: always;
```

Comment: font-smooth can have possible values auto,never,always and absolut-size.
http://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/font-smooth.htm

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
.sms {
    font-family:"Open Sans", "Regular";
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16pt;
    color:#04323b;
    letter-spacing:1px;

    /* font smooth */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);    
}
```

More detail : [How To Properly Smooth Font Using CSS3](http://www.icondeposit.com/blog%3ahow-to-properly-smooth-font-using-css3)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, problem is in this line:

```
font:"Open Sans" "Regular";
```

It is not valid font definition. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font) you can find some details about how font shortcut should be used.
Try to replace it with:

```
font-family:"Open Sans","Regular";
```

Also, not sure what is regular here. I know nothing about such property for fonts in css. Usually there is normal (like for font-weight), so I assume that it is font-family also.

Everything else looks to be Ok

Comment: i have got solution ;the solution is                                            .sms {
 font-family:"Open Sans";
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:23pt;
 color:#04323b;
 font-smooth: Sharp;
 
}